# Is there a library for making WP7 games leaderboard?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, leaderboard

I searched for an easy way to do that, and I found MAGADE

But unfortunately, registration has been stopped:

https://www.mogade.com/manage/accounts/new

I was happy when I heard that doing that using MAGADE is straight forward, and there is a working example provided. But now, I'm disappointed.

Do anyone have alternative(s) please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about [ScoreLoop?](http://www.scoreloop.com)  It's run by RIM (the Blackberry people) and is free.  It supports Android, IOS and WP7

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll accept it after trying that SDK.